# Add angular 6 to existing MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular6

i have a MVC project (.net framework 4.5) a large project many views and controllers i want to change index.cshtml view with angular 6 component.
mean only home page will be developed by using angular other will remain same as it is
tell me how to do it if it is possible

Comment: please see this http://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-create-an-angular-6-app-with-visual-studio-2017/

Comment: this is about how to create new project i need to add in existing project to replace only home page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to add angular 6 into your project and the rest would be same with this.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181888/Angular-in-ASP-NET-MVC-Web-API-Part

And this is also great short video with almost every detail of adding angular into ASP.Net MVC project.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbHSTJBhJ44

***Late october 2018 update:*** Angular 7 is released a couple of weeks ago. The video shows upgrading Angular 4 to 5. You can use the same approach to upgrade your Angular project to Angular 7 to get benefit of new nice features.

Comment: I watched the video and it is really helpful